# How to Display different views on one view controller on button click

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have three buttons on UI, want to display different views when user click on button. at a same time only one view display others would hide.

All views are different in design.

what is the appropriate way to do this?

[image]

Comment: There are multiple ways you can solve this. One thing is that you could do a function that hides all the views except the view you want to display. Have you even tried to solve this before asking?

Answer (score 1):

```
let view1 = UIView()
let view2 = UIView()
let view3 = UIView()

@IBAction func showView1BtnPressed() {
    hideOtherViewsExcept(forView: view1)
}

@IBAction func showView2BtnPressed() {
    hideOtherViewsExcept(forView: view2)
}

@IBAction func showView3BtnPressed() {
    hideOtherViewsExcept(forView: view3)
}

func hideOtherViewsExcept(forView view: UIView) {
    view1.isHidden = true
    view2.isHidden = true
    view3.isHidden = true
    view.isHidden = false
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but actually three views are using different controls so in this case how you will manage three views on interface builder ?

Comment: Do you have any code you could share with us? Because right now you're just asking for different views to show @Sneha

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOQ88.png

as you can see report will display tableview and other buttons (Scatter,Line Chart) will display simple UIView

Comment: I would suggest you to search for `container views`. There are a lot of guides on how to make things like that picture.